# Divide a span value by a static number - JS

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have a field in a table which takes in a value from an input field

```
    <td>€<span class="totalNumber"></span></td>
```

I have another field that has a static number so example 50%.

The result I want is the third field to have `totalNumber` divided by `.50` so my final field be my result.

Example: 
`totalNumber` takes in the value 100.
Second field is static `50%`
So my result field will be `50`

I've tried using: `var value = Math.floor(#totalNumber * .50);`

I'm not sure if that could be used or my syntax is just wrong.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? (*also you want it **multiplied** by `0.50` not divided*)

Comment: I've tried using var value=Math.floor(#totalNumber * .50); I'm not sure if that could be used or my syntax is just wrong.

Comment: @conye9980 What are you attempting with `#totalNumber`? You said you have an input field, yet no input field is present in your markup (example: `<input type="text"/>`). You would then be retrieving inputted value by starting with a DOM selector like the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: I'd suggest that you close this question (if only temporarily) to stop the loss of reputation (the imaginary points are irrelevant, but your ability to use the site is somewhat dependent on your reputation points), read both the "*[mcve]*" and the "*[ask]*" guidelines and then [edit] and improve your question before re-opening it (if you haven't worked out the answer in preparing the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need simple javascript.

```
var num = parseInt($('span.totalNumber').text());
var staticnum = parseInt($('span.staticNumber').text());

var answer = (num * staticnum)/100;

$('span.result').text(answer);
```

```js
var num = parseInt($('span.totalNumber').text());
var staticnum = parseInt($('span.staticNumber').text());

var answer = (num * staticnum)/100;

$('span.result').text(answer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Total Number : <span class="totalNumber">200</span>
</div>
<div>
Static Number : <span class="staticNumber">50%</span>
</div>

<div>
Result : <span class="result"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well . Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your provided code is to meager to provide a good answer but here is an example how you can do something like that.

At total you enter the number you want to divide.
At percent you add the percentage.
Both these inputs have a change event bound to them with the same handler so that if any of these changes it executes the handler. You probably want to check too if not both inputs are empty.

```js
var total = document.getElementById('totalValue').addEventListener('change', calculate);
var percent = document.getElementById('percentValue').addEventListener('change', calculate);

function calculate() {
  var total = document.getElementById('totalValue');
  var percent = document.getElementById('percentValue');
  var calc = document.getElementById('calculatedValue');

  calc.value = total.value * (percent.value / 100)
}
```

```html
<label for="totalValue">Total</label>
<input id="totalValue" type=text />
<br />

<label for="percentValue">Percent</label>
<input id="percentValue" type=text />
<br />

<label for="calculatedValue">Calculated</label>
<input id="calculatedValue" type=text />
```